# Rails Guard say 'Rspec results failed' and one empty spec give dependency errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, guard

I just updated my gems (Including rails to 4.1). I ran guard and everything worked fine. Then I created a new model and ran guard again. This time in the console everything looks good but the guard notification says `Rspec results failed`! I opened the spec of the newly created model (its empty) and just save it without changing. Then in the console i can see the following error :

```
    10:40:15 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/pubudu/Projects/sumaga-asapuwa'
    10:43:55 - INFO - Running: spec/models/dcache_spec.rb
    /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/pubudu/Projects/sumaga-asapuwa.bk/spec/models/dcache_spec.rb (LoadError)
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
    [1] guard(main)>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please share both the model and spec file.

Comment: doesn't sound like it's empty; sounds like it doesn't exist (hence the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard is watching the directory `/home/pubudu/Projects/sumaga-asapuwa` but it is trying to run a spec file in `/home/pubudu/Projects/sumaga-asapuwa.bk/spec/models` (i.e. with an extra `.bk` on the folder name.

In the `rspec` section of your `Guardfile` you should have a line like:

```
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
```

This is in the instruction to Guard that if a .rb file under the app directory changes, or is created, to run rspec on the corresponding spec file.  This is defined to be relative to the directory Guard is watching.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I removed the other directory and it worked :D